# Pandas: Find mean of maximum consectutive zero count in each interval

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have these following series. I want to find a mean of maximum consecutive zero counts on each interval.

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]) # [1, 2, 3]-> mean: 2
s2 = pd.Series([1, 1, 2]) # [0] -> 0
s3 = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1]) # [2] -> 2
s4 = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]) # [2, 3] -> 2.5
```

I tried to use `.shift` `.cumsum` `.eq` to solve but can't figure out the way to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter only `0`, add [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and last `mean`:

```
a = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()[s==0].value_counts().mean()
```

For second `Series` is returned missing value, so it is possible replace by `0` with trick `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`:

```
a = a if a == a else 0
```

All together:

```
L = [s1, s2, s3, s4]

def get_mean_consecutive_zeros(s):
    a = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()[s == 0].value_counts().mean()
    return a if a == a else 0

a = [get_mean_consecutive_zeros(s) for s in L]
print (a)
[2.0, 0, 2.0, 2.5]
```

Comment: Accepted. Although Chris's solution is faster but I'm looking for the Pandas solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

np.mean([sum(g) for k, g in groupby(s1.eq(0)) if k])
```

Output:

```
2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute the average zeros in the sequence:

1. Find the **unique count** of how many times **zero** appears **non-consequtively**. I have used python's built-in `itertool.groupby` function to achieve that.
2. Find the **total count** of **zeros** in the sequence. This can be done via built-in `collections.Counter`.
3. Compute the **average** via dividing `total_zero_count / unique_zero_count`

You can neatly wrap everything in a class like this

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

class ComputeAvgZero:
    """Count avg zeros in the given sequence."""

    def __init__(self, series):
        self.series : pd.Series = series

    def compute_avg_zero(self):
        """Main method that computes the average."""

        unique_zeros = self._count_unique_zeros(self.series) 
        total_zeros = self._count_total_zeros(self.series)

        if unique_zeros:
            avg_zeros = total_zeros / unique_zeros
        else:
            avg_zeros = 0

        return avg_zeros


    @staticmethod
    def _count_unique_zeros(series:pd.Series) -> int:
        """Counting the times zero appears non consecutively."""

        # keeping only the first of the consequtive zeroes
        series = [i[0] for i in itertools.groupby(series)]

        # count the non consequtive occurances of zero
        unique_zero_count = Counter(series)[0]

        return unique_zero_count

    @staticmethod
    def _count_total_zeros(series:pd.Series) -> int:
        """Count all the zeroes."""

        total_zero_count = Counter(series)[0]

        return total_zero_count
```

You can see the class in action here:

```
# compute average
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

obj = ComputeAvgZero(s)
avg_zeros = obj.compute_avg_zero()

print(avg_zeros)
```

This should give you

```
2.5
```